# Azure Table Storage: The string '' is not a valid AllXsd value

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm getting the following exception when I try to read from Table Storage. I got it after I added a `DateTime?` property.

**Exception:**

```
The current value 'String.Empty' type is not compatible with the expected 'System.DateTime' type.
```

**Inner exception:**

```
The string '' is not a valid AllXsd value.
```

I thought of the following solutions:

1. I get the provider to map the non-existing value to null
2. Update the object with a date (but I can't fetch it?)

Does anyone have a better idea on how to fix this?

**Stack trace:**

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The current value 'String.Empty' type is not compatible with the expected 'System.DateTime' type. ---> System.FormatException: The string '' is not a valid AllXsd value.
   at System.Xml.Schema.XsdDateTime..ctor(String text, XsdDateTimeFlags kinds)
   at System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDateTime(String s, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode dateTimeOption)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.ClientConvert.ChangeType(String propertyValue, Type propertyType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Services.Client.ClientConvert.ChangeType(String propertyValue, Type propertyType)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.AtomMaterializer.MaterializeDataValue(Type type, AtomContentProperty atomProperty, DataServiceContext context)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.AtomMaterializer.MaterializeDataValues(ClientType actualType, List`1 values, Boolean ignoreMissingProperties, DataServiceContext context)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.AtomMaterializer.MaterializeResolvedEntry(AtomEntry entry, Boolean includeLinks)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.AtomMaterializer.Materialize(AtomEntry entry, Type expectedEntryType, Boolean includeLinks)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.AtomMaterializer.DirectMaterializePlan(AtomMaterializer materializer, AtomEntry entry, Type expectedEntryType)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.AtomMaterializerInvoker.DirectMaterializePlan(Object materializer, Object entry, Type expectedEntryType)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.ProjectionPlan.Run(AtomMaterializer materializer, AtomEntry entry, Type expectedType)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.AtomMaterializer.Read()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.MaterializeAtom.MoveNextInternal()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.MaterializeAtom.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__b1`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Model

```
class Car : TableServiceEntity {

 public DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }
 public DateTime? LastUsed { get; set; }

// more properties

}
```

Query

```
 var sx = this.GetServiceContext();
 return (from x in sx.CreateQuery<Car>("Table") select x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution if anyone googles for it:

I'm using Azure Storage Explorer and it saved an empty string instead of a nullable date in one of the entities when I updated another property while testing.